# Split IP octet bytes

Tags: java, ip, byte

I had to split IP address bytes and preserve them in a tree. Here what I've implemented, but I've the feeling that there is a faster way to achieve the same goal. So if you have any ideas, please let me know :)

```
private static final int MAX_IP_BITS_SIZE = 16 * Byte.SIZE;

/**
 * Splits octet bytes in new byte array based on the splitter size.
 *
 * @param bytes address representation of IPv4 or IPv6 to be split.
 * @param splitSize is the amount of bit to split on. It could be from 1 to 7, otherwise returns unsplit bytes.
 * @return byte[] split version of the address bytes.
 */
private byte[] splitAddressBytes(byte[] bytes, final int splitSize)
{
    if (splitSize < 1 || splitSize > 7)
    {
        return bytes;
    }

    int byteIndex = 0;
    int changeByteIndex = 0;
    byte[] octetBytes = new byte[MAX_IP_BITS_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < Byte.SIZE * bytes.length; i++)
    {
        /*
         * Get byte index based on the splitter size, e.g. if the splitter size is 3, which mean that 'i % Byte.SIZE / splitSize' will
         * vary from 0 to 2, i.e. on each change between those value means we can move to the next index.
         */
        int inputBitIndex = i % Byte.SIZE;
        if (changeByteIndex != inputBitIndex / splitSize)
        {
            changeByteIndex = inputBitIndex / splitSize;
            byteIndex++;
        }

        /*
         * Traverse all bits one by one and check if it is set to 1, if so add it to the result byte. Get the bit at the position
         * "i / Byte.SIZE", then shift each bit at the first position and check if it is 1 or 0, i.e. i % Byte.SIZE is the position of
         * the bit that we want to check (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7), e.g. 128 is 1000 0000 and i % Byte.SIZE when i=0 is 0, as and i % Byte.SIZE
         * is 0, then do not shift, just AND 1000 0000 and 0x80 (which is 128 or 1000 0000). In that case the result is 128, which is
         * not 0 so the bit at that position is 1. Second attempt i=1, so i / Byte.SIZE = 0 and i % Byte.SIZE = 1. In that case we want
         * to check second bit which is 1000 0000 << 1 = 0000 0000, from where 0000 0000 & 1000 0000 = 0, so the bit at that position is
         * 0.
         */
        if ((bytes[i / Byte.SIZE] << inputBitIndex & 0x80) != 0)
        {
            /*
             * Now when we know that bit at that position (i) is set to 1 we have to place it to the particular byte at the desired
             * position based on the splitter size, i.e. 'octetBytes[byteIndex] & 0xFF' - get current value of the bit based on the
             * index (which also take into account split size) and apply bitwise OR with the bit that is set to 1 based on the bit
             * shift. So to determine the index position of the bit: '(Byte.SIZE - splitSize)' - get offset or the starting point from
             * the byte based on the splitter size. 'inputBitIndex % splitSize' - get which bit has to be set to 1, i.e. in case of
             * splitter set to 3 the block size is 3 and that will result in 0,1, or 2. '(Byte.SIZE - splitSize) + (inputBitIndex %
             * splitSize))' - combining offset and bit position we have the final bit position where we have to place the bit with value
             * 1. So with bit shift of 0x80 at that position, e.g. 1000 0000 >>> 5 = 0000 0100 we have the desired byte to add to
             * already existing. e.g. current byte is 0000 0000 and we want to add 1 at the correct position, 0000 0000 | 0x80 (which is
             * 128 or 1000 0000) >>> 5, where 5 is the bit position from 5 trough 7 in case of splitter size 3. e.g. 0000 0000 | 0000
             * 0100 = 0000 0100.
             */
            octetBytes[byteIndex] = (byte)(octetBytes[byteIndex] & 0xFF | (0x80 >>> (Byte.SIZE - splitSize) + (inputBitIndex % splitSize)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: We don't do code review here.  If you have *specific* concerns about details of your implementation, then please update your question with those.  Otherwise, if your method works then you could consider deleting this question and asking about it over at [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I though it's something that is missing as a topic in the stack. And maybe that could be interesting to others and may evolved to some better solution. If you still think I should remove it, I'll do it.